# Map "Right Alt" in Mac mode (=m) on Kinesis Advantage

Tags: keyboard

The "Right Alt" modifier key does not exist in the Mac keyboard layout – only "Left Alt".

How does one "find" this key and assign it using the F12 key programming mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kinesis support answered:

> The only way to get a Right Alt is to enter PC mode - Ctrl | Alt | Alt Gr | Ctrl. From there you can remap the embedded Windows keys (Command keys) located in the embedded "PrintScrn" and "Scroll Lock" keys (when Keypad is On, these two keys function as a L-Command and R-Command)."

Comment: Did anyone figure out how to remap command keys from PC mode? They are indeed accessible as PrintScrn and Scroll Lock keys in numpad layer, and when I enter the numpad layer and remap them elsewhere the remapping works while I'm in numpad layer - but stops working after I switch out of it

Answer (score 1):

(Program+F6) gets you into 'PC Mode' if you want the [Ctrl | Alt ][ Alt | Ctrl] setup... (This is the Advantage2, i think same applies to the Advantage1).

Note: there is a SmartSet GUI app now by Kinesis that you can reassign/map/macro keys if you want a more custom layout for your Mac ... but this is usually the only remapping I want so the (Program+F6) works out for me.